# Can I replace laptop SSD harddrive with normal drive without voiding the warranty?

Tags: ssd, thinkpad

I have a Thinkpad w510 with a 128 GB SSD drive. However, I have found out that storage capacity of the SSD disc is insufficient.

My question is: **Is it possible to a get new laptop 500 GB harddrive and can I replace it without voiding the computer's warranty.**

Comment: That depends on the vendor/seller. Normally, swapping components voids the warranty, so does opening the laptop.

Comment: @Bobby - That is true, except for memory and HDD's. You can change them usually without voiding the warranty. At least that has been the case with my last few laptops (HP, Fujitsu Siemens and Gericom).

Comment: why not boot from the ssd and use an external usb hd for what ever you need more capacity for?

Comment: Actually i have installed vmware nd i have 5-6 virtual machine which i want to work on . Each VM is about 30 GB so i need more space. SSD is good speed but i need more space

Comment: *> That is true, except for memory and HDD's.*   Exactly; that’s why most laptop mfgs specifically place the RAM and drive in a user-accessible area and mark it on the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can replace the disk without voiding the warranty. For instructions on how to do it, see [T510 HW manual](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-74250). Also, see the pictures in this answer, [T510 drive bay](https://superuser.com/a/446214/147104)

However, as MicTech says, your should consider putting the 500GB disc in the Ultra Bay with an adapter, e.g. see [Ultra Bay HDD adapter](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-75377). This way you can have the OS on the SSD (fast boot etc.) and have capacity demanding data on the slower but larger 500GB disc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can replace it yourself. Look on the underside of the laptop and look for the harddrive compartment. Unscrew the screws and lift the lid and you'll see your SSD harddrive in there. Just replace it with a normal 2.5" harddrive and all should be ok. It's quite easy so give it a try.

Comment: btw, make sure the connector that connects to the SSD drive is compatible with the new harddrive that you are installing. Most likely  a SATA connector.

Comment: @Mirage: If your laptop has two disk drives, you can just add one more. Otherwise, just remember that an SSD is still costly and useful. Take care with backups, and then take an image of the disk with a product that supports restoring into a larger drive.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, because SSD drive have SATA interface and possibly same size like standart mechanical 2,5" HDD.

This is OK for ThinkPads, you don't worry about warranty.

or

ThinkPad w510 has Ultrabay III, where you can connect adapter for HDD, which can take any 2.5" HDD.

UPDATE: There is no limitation for size, basically. Limitation is size of HDD.

Comment: whats the max size of laptop HDD i can get and rough price for that

Answer (score 1):

As long as you buy your components from Lenovo or an authorized reseller and they are a valid Lenovo FRU Part Number for the machine in question they will carry the warranty of the machine.  Only physical abuse would invalidate your warranty.  This is true for anything that's classified as customer replaceable - practically this is hard drives, Ultrabay devices, RAM, WLAN and WWAN adapters.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, your warranty won't be voided. If you need to send it in for warranty though, keep the old hard drive to put in before sending it back

Comment: *If you bed to send it in for warranty though*?   `o.O`

Comment: Damn you auto correct

Comment: So what was it supposed to say? I can’t think of anything that fits.

Comment: Need......... Is the character minimum reached yet

Comment: Good point! However, I was recommended by the warranty service provider to remove the drive before sending in the laptop (they replace a faulty motherboard on my old T42)

Comment: @fredob314 Ahhh, I haven't dealt with Lenovo's warranty yet... The other computer companies I have dealt with want EVERYTHING in there