# How do I add an additional hard drive to a Thinkpad W510?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W510. The solid state drive (SSD) is only 120GB. My problem is that I want one additional hard drive. So my question is:

How do I buy - preferable at Ebay - an adapter and add a hard drive to the DVD drive slot?

Comment: This is almost the same question as http://superuser.com/q/154075/147104. Should they be merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The W510 [already has a drive bay](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/2nd-hard-drive-in-a-W510/td-p/346539) for a second hard-drive, SSD, etc., but you need a *ThinkPad Serial ATA Hard Drive Bay Adapter III* (part [#43N3412](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-73170)). You can get them [from Lenovo](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/itemdetails/43N3412/460/FDCD14101F7E452CBBA91660EB85C922) for $60 plus shipping or [on eBay](http://www.ebay.ca/sch/i.html?_nkw=43N3412&_sop=15&_sc=1) for under $15 (including shipping).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. 1) Is the hard disk which is put inside the bay is normal SATA hard disk and i can buy from ebay or its another hard disk. 2) That forum link you gave me in the end says that i have to take DVD out??. 3) How can i open the laptop to put Hard disk inside

Comment: Can i buy this from Ebay http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/12-7mm-2nd-Sata-HDD-Caddy-IBM-Lenovo-Thinkpad-T420-T520-W520-W510-T510-NEW-/300678214655?pt=US_Drive_Bay_Caddies&hash=item4601d173ff

Comment: **(1)** Yes, look at the drive compatibility section of the [adapter page](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-73170). **(2)** That was for the SlimBay adapter. You may have to remove the DVD for the UltraBay adapter as well because it looks about the same, but the page for it says nothing about removing the DVD drive, so you would have to check the instructions that come with it (there is no documentation for it on the Lenovo site). **(3)** I’m sure the documentation will state that as well, but there should be a tab or screw.

Comment: sorry i got confused. what is the diff between ultrbay and slimbay adapter

Comment: *> Can i [sic] buy this from Ebay [sic]…*   Yes, that should work. It specifically mentions the W510, so it should be compatible. That particular seller has [sold 17](http://offer.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewBidsLogin&item=300678214655) of them in the past few months. Unfortunately that seller’s [sales](http://feedback.ebay.com.au/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&ftab=AllFeedback&userid=ny-compu-tek&items=200) are private, so you cannot check the feedback for those specific items, but you can probably cross-reference the sales and feedbacks if you really want peace of mind.

Comment: *> sorry i got confused. what is the diff between ultrbay and slimbay adapter*   It doesn’t look like there’s any significant difference. I thought maybe there was a slim version of the Ultra Bay, but that does not seem to be the case. It seems that they are just different names from different manufacturers. In fact, the only thing I can find about the Slim Bay seems to be people just calling the Ultra Bay the *Ultra Bay Slim* for some reason.

Comment: Should i buy 5400rpm or 7200rpm HDD and what is SATA1,SATA2 , SATA3 HDD. Can i buy anyone

Comment: That’s up to you and your needs; the adapter supports both. In my opinion, if it is just your backup drive where you keep your documents, video, music, etc. (especially if you don’t use it frequently), then you may as well just get a 5400 RPM drive since it will use less power while in use (i.e., longer battery life), should create less heat and noise, and be cheaper.